# Why am I getting "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" when using a TO_DATE but works on Oracle SQL developer? (Using Node)

Tags: node.js, oracle

I have the following schema...

```
CREATE TABLE CALL_DATE(
  ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  SERVER VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  MADE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CALL_SERVER_CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ID, SERVER)
);
```

And I have the following code using the node oracle driver...

```
const SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM CALL_DATE WHERE MADE_DATE = TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD')";
const SQL_FMT = "YYYY-MM-DD";

query(cmd, params){
    params = params || [];
    CallDate.validatePool(this.pool);
    return this.connection.then((connection)=>{
        console.log("Connection Created "+JSON.stringify(params));
        return connection.execute(
            cmd,
            params
        );
    });
}
getCallsOnDate(date){
    date = moment(new Date(date));
    console.log(`The date is ${date.format(SQL_FMT)}`);
    return this.query(
        SELECT_QUERY,
        [date.format(SQL_FMT)]
    ).catch((err)=>{
        Logger.log("error", `Error getting call dates on ${date} ${err}`);
        throw new Error(err);
    });
}
...
// works
obj.query(`SELECT * FROM CALL_DATE`).then((result)=>{
    console.log(`Query completed ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
});
// Fails
obj.getCallsOnDate("12/21/2012").then((result)=>{
    console.log(`getCallsOnDate completed ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
})
```

Everything works for the Query function but when I try the date function I get...

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

If I run the following in Oracle SQL Developer Everything works fine...

```
SELECT * FROM CALL_DATE WHERE MADE_DATE = TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

What am I missing, why does it work in SQL developer but not the node code?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but - in Oracle, use VARCHAR**2** datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Oops I ported this code from MySQL and so I needed to update my query to look like this...

```
const SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM CALL_DATE WHERE MADE_DATE = TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD')";
```

Notice `:1` instead of `?`

Comment: Does it mean that you fixed it?